# How to make a React component re-render when a value from outside changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

My project uses Meteor and React.
I have this class `WebRTC` for managing WebRTC-related logic:

```
class WebRTC {  
  this.isCalling = false;    
  ...  
}
```

And also this class (React component) `Conversation`, which has a property named `webRTC` that is an instance of the above `WebRTC` class:

```
class Conversation extends React.Component {  
  render() {  
    const { webRTC } = this.props;
    if (webRTC.isCalling) return (<p>In call</p>);
    return (<p>Available</p>)
  }  
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  const user = Meteor.user();
  const webRTC = new WebRTC();
  return {
    user,
    webRTC,
  }
}, Conversation);
```

What I want to do is whenever the `webRTC` instance's `isCalling` value change, the `Conversation` component gets re-rendered. The current way doesn't work. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the state change of isCalling in WebRTC to trigger a state change in your component. The state change will cause render() to be called.

Add a method to your WebRTC class like this...

```
function setOnCallStatusChange(onCallStatusChange) {
    this.onCallStatusChange = onCallStatusChange;
  }
```

And presumably there is some place in your WebRTC class where you learn about changes to the call status and this is where you are assigning true or false to the .isCalling member. Wherever this code is inside of WebRTC, add a line like the following:

```
if (this.onCallStatusChange) {onCallStatusChange(this.isCalling);}
```

Basically, the above changes add a notification interface to your WebRTC class. You must also change your Conversation component to bind to this interface and use it to update the Conversation component's state (triggering a render). The code below shows how to do this:

```
class Conversation extends React.Component {  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isCalling: false; }
    this.handleCallStatusChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleCallStatusChange(isCalling) {
    this.setState({isCalling});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.webrtc.setOnCallStatusChange(this.handleCallStatusChange);
  }

  render() {  
    if (this.state.isCalling) return (<p>In call</p>);
    return (<p>Available</p>)
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not re-rendered because createContainer is updated only with reactive variable, for example subscriptions (or reactive variable). In your case the container does not have any utility and you can move that logic inside the Conversation component. Doing this you could assign the webRc variable to the state, so the component re-renders on every change.